# Rails Actions - What is the correct way to handle JSON and HTML requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My application currently handles HTML requests only and I would like to extend some actions to also  handle JSON requests. Many of the controller actions perform redirects, set session values (flash) depending on whether the request was successful.

How can I incorporate responds_to to change action behavior based on request format for an action such as this:

```
 def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])      
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = {:success => "User Created."}
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
        session[:username] = @user.username
    redirect_to(:controller => 'lists', :action => 'index')
  else
     flash[:notice] = {:error => @user.errors}
    render('new')
  end
end
```

So as you can see I am checking to see if the model is persisted and then either redirecting or rendering the form again. How can I maintain this current behavior but also handle requests in JSON? JSON requests will not need to perform redirects etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])      
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = {:success => "User Created."}
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
        session[:username] = @user.username
         respond_to do |format|
            format.json {render :json => @user}
            format.html{redirect_to(:controller => 'lists', :action => 'index')}
         end

  else
     flash[:notice] = {:error => @user.errors}
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json {render :json => @user.errors}
         format.html{render('new')}
      end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement in my application. I chose to create a different set of controllers for the JSON API, since there's very little in common to the HTML and JSON controllers. It also makes it simpler to use gems that are specific to API building and to JSON (RocketPants in my case).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I really hope duplicating all my controllers and actions is not necessary.